# Hold open a PowerShell Window to see result

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am attempting to hold open a PowerShell window to see a result, I am calling the script from a shortcut so it can be run as admin.

I have attempted calling it from a batch file with the pause command, yet it still closes instantly

I have attempted to ask for user Credential input with "Get-Credential" at the end of the script, yet the window still closes.

I've also used a pause command, yet it still closes.

The actual script is just an AD sync command.

```
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta
Pause
```

Comment: If you use a shortcut why not using the command line option `-NoExit`?  ‍♂️